# Gnuplot - How to place y-values above bars when using Histogram style?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am currently using a script to generate histogram plots, e.g., by doing:

```
set style histogram cluster gap 4
plot for [COL=2:10] 'example.dat' u COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader(COL)
```

Now I wish to add the y-values (numbers) above the bars in the histogram but adding `w labels` gives the 'Not enough columns for this style' error.

```
plot for [COL=2:10] 'example.dat' u COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader(COL), \
    for [COL=2:10] 'example.dat' u COL title '' w labels
```

Is it possible to add y-labels using the histogram style?

Note: I know that there are examples for plotting `with boxes`. I wish to make this work with the histogram style if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a test datafile I came up with:

example.dat

```
 hi world foo bar baz qux
 1   2     3   4   5   6    
 4   5     7   3   6   5
```

Here's the script I used to plot it:

```
set yrange [0:*]
GAPSIZE=4
set style histogram cluster gap 4
STARTCOL=2                 #Start plotting data in this column (2 for your example)
ENDCOL=6                   #Last column of data to plot (10 for your example)
NCOL=ENDCOL-STARTCOL+1     #Number of columns we're plotting 
BOXWIDTH=1./(GAPSIZE+NCOL) #Width of each box.
plot for [COL=STARTCOL:ENDCOL] 'example.dat' u COL:xtic(1) w histogram title columnheader(COL), \
    for [COL=STARTCOL:ENDCOL] 'example.dat' u (column(0)-1+BOXWIDTH*(COL-STARTCOL+GAPSIZE/2+1)-0.5):COL:COL notitle w labels
```

Each cluster of histograms takes a total width of 1 unit on the x axis.  We know how many widths we need (the number of boxes +4 since that is the gapsize). We can calculate the width of each box (`1/(N+4)`).  We then plot the histograms as normal.  (Note that I added `with histogram` to the plot command).

According to the builtin help, labels require 3 columns of data (`x y label`).  In this case, the y position and the label are the same and can be read directly from the column `COL`.  The x position of the first block is centered 0 (and has a total width of 1).  So, the first block is going to be located at `x=-0.5+2*BOXWIDTH`.  The 2 here is because the gap is 4 boxwidths -- two on the left and 2 on the right.  The next block is going to be located at `-0.5+3*BOXWIDTH`, etc.  In general, (as a function of `COL`) we can write this as

```
-0.5+BOXSIZE*(COL-STARTCOL+1+GAPSIZE/2)
```

We need to shift this to the right by 1 unit for each additional block we read.  Since each block corresponds to 1 line in the data file, we can use pseudo-column `0` (i.e. `column(0)` or `$0`) for this since it gets incremented for each "record/line" gnuplot reads.  The 0th record holds the titles, the first record holds the first block.  Since we want a function which returns 0 for the first record, we use `column(0)-1`.  Putting it all together, we find that the x-position is:

```
(column(0)-1-0.5+BOXSIZE*(COL-STARTCOL+1+GAPSIZE/2))
```

which is equivalent to what I have above.

Comment: Wow, so much effort and no feedback from the OP. Regardless, have you tried this solution? Does it work?

Comment: @EduardoBezerra -- I did try it (and was pretty proud of it too), and it did work.  Why, are you having problems with it?

Comment: Quite the opposite, now I tried it and it works beautifully! Naming the variables in your solution helped a lot to understand the trick. Too bad this is not as easy as putting labels on a curve. Now, I just run one script to create the data table and plot the clustered histogram, and every label appears sitting exactly on top of each bar, perfectly aligned.

Comment: @EduardoBezerra -- Oh good.  You had me worried that I had posted a garbage solution when you asked about it yesterday.

Comment: @mgilson, Sorry my HDD crashed, will definitely pick your answer once I have tried it. Thanks for being so detailed.

Comment: WOW your answer worked out of the box.. I tried to shift the numbers higher, but i could not figure out. any advice